# multiple sprite different name

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

How do I create multiple instance of the same sprite with different name as in shap1, shape2, shape3, etc. Then the function will change the color of the sprite through getChildByName? Whether I create a new instance, the old sprite will be overwrite by the new sprite and when I call the old "shape1", it will be null. How do I retain all sprite?

```
    var c:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
    var s:Sprite = new Sprite();

private function shapeCreate() {
        s.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
         s.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
         s.graphics.endFill();
         s.name = "shape1";
             s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,chgColorBlue);
             s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,chgColorReset);
             c.addChild(s);
    addElement(c);
}

    private function chgColorBlue(e:MouseEvent):void {
        e.currentTarget.graphics.beginFill(0x000099);
        e.currentTarget.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
        e.currentTarget.graphics.endFill();
       }
```

Comment: I've added an answer to your previous question...

Comment: Thank, add my comment to the previous post.

Answer (score 0):

You use the same Sprite instance so when you call the `shapeCreate()` method it overrides it.

You should define as many Sprites as you need and apply the shape creation to them separately so there will be no override.

```
var c:UIComponent = new UIComponent(); 

//Creating the Sprite instances for the shapes
var s1:Sprite = new Sprite();
s1.name = "s1_sp";
var s2:Sprite = new Sprite();
s2.name = "s2_sp";
var s3:Sprite = new Sprite();
s3.name = "s3_sp";

private function shapeCreate(s:Sprite)
{
    s.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
    s.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
    s.graphics.endFill();
    s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,chgColorBlue);
    s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,chgColorReset);
    c.addChild(s);
    addElement(c);
}

private function chgColorBlue(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //Just added this line to clear the old graphics
    e.currentTarget.graphics.clear();

    e.currentTarget.graphics.beginFill(0x000099);
    e.currentTarget.graphics.drawEllipse(7,35,18,12);
    e.currentTarget.graphics.endFill();
}


//Creating the shapes
shapeCreate(s1);
shapeCreate(s2);
shapeCreate(s3);
```

I hope it helps and that's what you wanted to do.

Good luck,
Rob